# Is there a way If someone accesses a directory in my laravel project, I redirect them to homepage?

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5.8

I have a laravel project (version 5.8 if being specific) where CSS and JS files are in subdirectories in public directory.
For example, there is a `www.mysite.test/css/app.css` that I want to allow.
But I would like to redirect users if they try to access a url like `www.mysite.test/css`

Currently, it shows a blank white screen, and that is not desired.

Important: Files in the directory must be accessible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevention of direct access to folder within public folder using .htaccess not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911647/prevention-of-direct-access-to-folder-within-public-folder-using-htaccess-not-w)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access files in storage folder only through Auth Middleware and Token based authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37372317/access-files-in-storage-folder-only-through-auth-middleware-and-token-based-auth)

Answer (score 1):

what you need to do is to add this code in your web.php routes, for exemple:

```php
Route::fallback(function () {
    return redirect()->back();
});
```

source : [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#fallback-routes)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that does not do what i want, it redirects the not found directories, But if the specified directory is available, it still shows a blank white screen.
for example: www.mysite.test/not-available-css : redirects to home, 
But www.mysite.test/css shows a black screen

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered here. see this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911647/prevention-of-direct-access-to-folder-within-public-folder-using-htaccess-not-w?rq=1)!

Just add in your upload folder .htaccess file with content:

```
Deny from  all
```

Comment: Sorry But that was not what I am looking for, the link you provided is trying to Deny access to some files in some directories, 
But What I want is to allow access to files, but redirect if their parent directory is called. As I said, www.mysite.test/css/app.css must be accessible, but www.mysite.test/css redirects to homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Two options here,

#### 1. Using an index.php

Basically you add an `index.php` file in your `css` directory and you use this index file to redirect the users with something like this

```
<?php
header('Location: http://www.mysite.test/');
?>
```

#### 2. .htaccess

Or you can use it to allow only selected files to be read from everyone.